# jQuery light box zoom effects

Tags: jquery, lightbox, zooming

Does anyone know how to do the Flickr style:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/bmse/34377828322/in/explore-2017-05-08/

Photo zoom effects + lightbox via jQuery?

If you click the image, image zoomed and covering whole page and allowing a mouse control image movement...
On Mobile - a little zooming change the image into high quality image.

Thanks

Comment: This is very likely custom JavaScript that the people at Flickr wrote: It's probably not an off-the-shelf script. So if you want that same behavior, you'll have to build it yourself from its pieces: A background shadow cover, a zoom animation, mouse tracking, a zoom out at the right time, and mobile support. I'd recommend that if you don't want to build it yourself, you find some other lightbox script that's open-source code and has "close enough" behavior to be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I saw similar effect in web.whatsapp.com, clicking on picture, zoomed, and moving mouse move the image, perfectly coded.
You are right I will try to build it my self and share with all :)

Comment: you can create your own , just all the trick is in the move calculation ,
see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/331177ns/1/)

Comment: Brilliant bRIMOs, thank you so much for sharing such useful codes, would be very helpful to create my own effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jquery PAN plugin to have zoom effects. You can see zoom [example here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Image-Zoom-Pan-Plugin-With-jQuery-ZooMove/) and another [example here](http://www.samilhazir.com/pan/).

You need to merge two plugins to have achieve your need. Apply class which PAN plugin need to your big image of gallery plugin so both plugin will work.

You can download code from [here](https://github.com/saplumbaga/jquery.pan)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very close to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of [those jQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/lightbox/) and adjust it too you needs.
Hope this helps.
SYA :)